# How to debug the ajax request in django

Tags: ajax, django

I know that for example:

```
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        k = 'p' % 1
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(dict()),  mimetype='application/javascript')
    else:
        k = 'p' % 1
        return render_to_response('index.html',locals());

url(r'^$', 'app.home'),
```

If I use the browser to visit the home page, django will return a debug page to me and show that there is an error in `k = 'p' % 1`

But if I use the `$.ajax()` to send a post to this view, the console of chrome only show `POST http://(some url here):8000/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)`

so is there any good way to debug the second case?
I have no idea about debug the django, is there anybody have better way to debug the django?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry) (and the corresponding raven)

(the `Network` tab should be able to show you the request and the corresponding response. i believe newer django versions even give you a more bare-bones version of the stacktrace if the request was ajax)

Answer (score 0):

There is an `error CallBack` in ajax. It will spew out the actual error.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{% url 'url_name_for_your_view_here' %}',
        data: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'},
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response) {
            //do something here if everything goes well
        },
        error: function(rs, e) {
            alert(rs.responseText); //throw actual error, just for debugging purpose
            alert('Oops! something went worng..'); // alert user that something goes wrong
         }
     });
```

Comment: If he is experiencing 500 errors, his app is likely crashing, and that ajax response could potentially not be sent at all

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of third party apps make debugging ajax easier. I've used this in the past with success: https://github.com/yaniv-aknin/django-ajaxerrors

Or if you prefer not use an app, chrome developer tools will likely be enough, as is suggested in this thread: [Django: Are there any tools/tricks to use on debugging AJAX response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059071/django-are-there-any-tools-tricks-to-use-on-debugging-ajax-response)