# stack trace from manage.py runserver not appearing

Tags: python, django

Django's `runserver` command doesn't output a stack trace when I append `--traceback --verbosity 2`:

```
➫ python manage.py runserver --traceback --verbosity 2
Validating models...

0 errors found
July 24, 2013 - 11:45:12
Django version 1.5.1, using settings 'base.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[24/Jul/2013 11:45:27] "POST /login/get_associations/ HTTP/1.0" 500 13220
```

Are there other command line switches or logging configuration I can add to get `runserver` to print a stack trace when there is a `500`?

Comment: I don't think there is any such switch. What we usually do is use `DEBUG=True`, in which case the traceback and other information goes to the browser. Why is this not sufficient?

Comment: DEBUG is set to True already. I'm trying to debug an AJAX-based system.

Comment: Then probably you want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14171520/how-to-debug-the-ajax-request-in-django. I think you can also use Firebug, which is not mentioned in that thread.

Comment: I'm doing something like that at the moment where I'm watching the response from the Chrome WebKit Debugger and reading through the HTML stack trace. Ideally I'd like to just be able to read the stack trace in the command line or tail a log file.

Comment: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/420/ ; https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process_exception

Comment: You can install firebug plugin in firefox browser, and can see any kind of errors in the firebug panel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print a stack trace to stdout on errors in Django while using manage.py runserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886275/print-a-stack-trace-to-stdout-on-errors-in-django-while-using-manage-py-runserve)

Answer (score 31):

Agreed that this is convenient, especially for MVVM-centric app development (e.g. Angular/Ember front-end). Also this is helpful when others are testing out the front-end.

As you mentioned, this isn't provided by `DEBUG=True`. You can add a stacktrace when running `./manage.py runserver` by adding the following to the *settings.py* file:

```python
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

This syntax comes from the Django documentation [Configuring Logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) and can be further modified to increase or decrease the amount of console-logging.

Also note that *5XX* responses are raised as ERROR messages and *4XX* responses are raised as WARNING messages.