# Django: How to debug a server 500 error

Tags: django

I'm not sure what to post here, so if you could forgive me and tell me what might be helpful if anything I would appreciate it.

I am creating two objects and putting them into the database with a POST from and iOS app using AFNetworking to a function based view. Everything works and my USER and ADDRESS objects are inserted properly into the database. I've put breakpoints in my python code and I can't catch any exceptions... All I get in the console is the server 500 error and no indication of what it is... I'm really frustrated and I have a feeling the answer is simple... How do I debug this?

Comment: Which console are you talking about? The JS console in your web browser? If you have DEBUG = True in your settings.py file then django provides some pretty helpful tracebacks. To see the traceback switch from your "console" tab the the "network" tab (I'm assuming you're using chrome here) and refresh the page. Find the request that's causing the 500 response code and click it and check the response from the server. This should show you the Django traceback and give you a better idea of what's going wrong.

Comment: I apologize, I just edited my question to have more information. I'm not using a browser as my edits indicate. Thoughts? And I'm using pycharm and that is the console.

Comment: Ah I see, so you'd like to see a traceback in the pycharm console? I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23818289/3175260) will help you.