# Django. The number won't increase after ajax call

Tags: jquery, python, json, ajax, django

I am rewriting this question, because I am uncertain if I would produce a duplicate if posting a new one. The first comments is answer to the original question.

I have a exam project which is partly to write a Django site with notes where a logged in user can vote on a note.

The html code, urls, view and jQuery don't give any errors. However, the number of likes will not increase after clicking the thumbs up icon from Bootstrap.

**Updated with suggestions form Liαrεz and Sebastian Wozny**

Can anyone please help me?

**JS file**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
$("#increase_num_likes_thumb").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': $.cookie('csrftoken') },
        url: $('#num_likes_url').val(),
        success: function(data){
            result = JSON.parse(data);
            if (result.error){
                consloe.log(result.error_text);
            }else{
                var num_likes_updated = result['num_likes_updated'];
                $("#num_likes_div").html(num_likes_updated);
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {% if notes %}
            {% for note in notes %}
                <div class="col-sm-5" style="border: 1px solid; margin: 10px;">
                    <h3 class="page-header"><a href="{% url 'notes:detailnote' %}?id={{ note.id }}">{{ note.label }}</a></h3>
                    <div style="padding: 5px;"> 
                        {{ note.body }}
                        <p>
                            <div>
                                <a href="/notes/?id={{ note.id }}/increase_num_likes/" id="increase_num_likes_thumb">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="num_likes_div">
                                {{ note.num_likes }}
                            </div>
                        </p>
                        <input type="hidden" id="num_likes_url" value="/notes/increase_num_likes/?id={{ note.id }}" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls import include
from notes.views import increase_num_likes

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(P<id>[\d\w]+)/increase_num_likes/$',
    increase_num_likes, name='increase_numlikes'),
```

,

**Views.py**

```
import json
from django.http import HttpResponse
def increase_num_likes(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id', None)
    if id is None:
        note = get_object_or_404(Note, id=id)
        data = {'error': True, 'error_text': 'Not ID supplied'}
    else:
        note = Note.objects.get(id=int(id))
        note.num_likes += 1
        note.save()
        data = {'num_likes_updated': note.num_likes}
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059071/django-are-there-any-tools-tricks-to-use-on-debugging-ajax-response and let us know more on the error.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you reccon more info is needed?

Comment: It seems like I am passing two arguments, not one, when updating the page with my ajax call. Hmm...

Comment: do you care about the number `16` in the url?  in that case your view function needs to accept a second argument.  if you don't care then you shouldn't use a regex group in the url pattern, so that Django doesn't try to call the view function with two args. i.e. don't use brackets around the `\d+`

Comment: you django view code doesnt seem logical. how can your note.save() if note = None?

Comment: @Anentropic Thanks for your reply. I get the new url when I click the anchor, however the count of likes does not change.

Comment: @Mox Thanks for mention that. I tried with note = Note.objects.get(pk=note_id) instead of the id and if else as you mention. However, this does not change anything as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in `url: $('#num_likes_url').val()`

```
<input type="hidden" id="num_likes_url" value="/notes/?id={{ note.id }}/increase_num_likes/" >
```

so `value`is `"/notes/?id={{ note.id }}/increase_num_likes/"` which is not a valid URI. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme):

```
<scheme name> : <hierarchical part> [ ? <query> ] [ # <fragment> ]
```

The correct way would be to call if you'd like to retrieve the id as a get argument.

```
"/notes/increase_num_likes/?id={{ note.id }}"
```

your urls.py

```
url(r'^increase_num_likes/$', increase_num_likes, name='increase_numlikes')
```

**Alternatively** you could make use of djangos url parsing:

urls.py

```
url(r'^(P<id>[\d\w]+)/increase_num_likes/$', increase_num_likes, name='increase_numlikes')
```

views.py

```
from import json

def increase_num_likes(request,id):
if id is None:
    note = get_object_or_404(Note, id=id)
    data = {'error': True, 'error_text': 'Not ID supplied'}
else:
    note = Note.objects.get(id=int(id))
    note.num_likes += 1
    note.save()
    data = {'num_likes_updated': note.num_likes}
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        {% if notes %}
            {% for note in notes %}
                <div class="col-sm-5" style="border: 1px solid; margin: 10px;">
                    <h3 class="page-header"><a href="{% url 'notes:detailnote' %}?id={{ note.id }}">{{ note.label }}</a></h3>
                    <div style="padding: 5px;"> 
                        {{ note.body }}
                        <p>
                            <div>
                                <a href="/notes/?id={{ note.id }}/increase_num_likes/" id="increase_num_likes_thumb">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div id="num_likes_div">
                                {{ note.num_likes }}
                            </div>
                        </p>
                        <input type="hidden" id="num_likes_url" value="/notes/increase_num_likes/?id={{ note.id }}" >
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Furthermore it's important to set the correct headers:

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/#ajax) suggests you are required to set the `X-CSRFToken` header when posting data with AJAX that is not a form which contains the `{% csrftoken %}` tag.

With jquery acquiring the token on the client is straightforward:

```
var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
```

Set the right header on your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': $.cookie('csrftoken') }
      url: $('#num_likes_url').val()
    })
```

I suspect your POST never reaches your view and is caught by CSRFProtectionMiddleware

Comment: After DOM is loaded I have pasted the js code from the [Documention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/csrf/#ajax). The long version, not the short you like you suggest. And after that in the js file, I have pasted the function csrfSafeMethod(method) from Django. Not in headers like you suggest.

Comment: I have updated the question based on you suggestion. However, I do believe I have found an error in my html. Is seems like I am using the same id on several html elements on the same page. Shame on me. Could this be the reason for not working?

Comment: That seems unlikely, even though it's against HTML standards, typical implementations will silently ignore the error.

Comment: It worked once with the **url(r'^(P<id>[\d\w]+)/increase_num_likes/$', increase_num_likes, name='increase_numlikes')** . I also changed the **value** of **num_likes_url** like you suggested. The first note changed from 0 til 1 vote. So that is great. However, if I try to vote again I get an **404 error**. Get the same error if a different user try to vote. The **console** says it's an **ananoymous function** line 5 in the **js file**

Comment: what URI are you  getting the 404 from, can you copy paste the url?

Comment: yeah so you are still querying the old url, try hitting   
localhost:8000/notes/16/increase_num_likes/ repeatedly

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The url you're suggestion is missing ?id=, so I get an 404 error. However, refreashing the page with the url localhost:8000/notes/?id=16/increase_num_likes/ does not seem to do anything.

Comment: if you're using my urlconfig then you have to use my views.py in which there is no ?id=, you're mixing code together that does not belong together. the url i have posted will work for my view + my urls.py

Comment: Not easy to be a code rookie ;-) I have tried to make it work bu using your code here, both the url, view and html. However, this raise and error of unexpected < when activating the script. Seems like there is something wrong with Json parse part of the ajax. Honestly, I am becoming a bit lost here. So I wonder if I should start over, trying another aproach to this add likes to a note problem. Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: can you upload your code to github and share? i'll fix it

Comment: I have not commited that changes done in this tread. However, the repo is here https://github.com/jimma1/harvsterOfNotes

Comment: You have got a pull request on github.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your AJAX view to:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def increase_num_likes(request):
    id = request.GET.get('id', None)
    if id is None:
        note = get_object_or_404(Note, id=id)
        data = {'error':True, 'error_text': 'Not ID supplied'}
    else:
        note = Note.objects.get(id=int(id))
        note.num_likes += 1
        note.save()
        data = {'num_likes_updated': note.num_likes}
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

and change your AJAX .done to .success managing the error:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#increase_num_likes_thumb").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: $('#num_likes_url').val()
        })
        .success: function(data) {
            result = JSON.parse(data);  # Parse the data received
            if (result.error){
                console.log(result.error_text);
            }else{
                var num_likes_updated = result['num_likes_updated'];
                $("#num_likes_div").html(num_likes_updated);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: I get an error on the .success: function (data) { . Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token: