# Storing ajax post data in django model

Tags: angularjs, django

Objects are created using shell while using the same command, but object is not created while I post the data using Angular from another port. I didn't get any errors. I have tried by giving values manually also.

```
def insertCompany_type(request, *args, **kwargs):
      if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
         data = json.loads(request.body)
         c_type = data["subject"]
         user = request.user
         Company_Type.objects.create(user=user, type=c_type)
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

Comment: Format the question properly

Comment: while i giving Company_Type.objects.create(user_id =1, type='customer') command in shell, objects are created.. But the same command is not working while posting the data from angular js

Answer (score 3):

You should use some tool like chrome developer tools. See tab "Network" in it. Also you should use decorator `csrf_exempt` in your code. And, finally, you need to check raw data from user.

```
@csrf_exempt
def insertCompany_type(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        c_type = data["subject"]
        user = request.user
        Company_Type.objects.create(user = user,type = c_type)
        return JsonResponse({'status': 'ok'})
    return JsonResponse({'status': 'error'})
```

**UPDATE**. Yes, i agree. csrf_exempt is a bad idea. Most better add header in request on client side, like that:

```
angular
  .module('thinkster')
  .run(run);

run.$inject = ['$http'];

/**
* @name run
* @desc Update xsrf $http headers to align with Django's defaults
*/
function run($http) {
  $http.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
  $http.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
}
```

Full version is [here](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial)

Comment: Please do not randomly set @csrf_exempt tag - in your ajax call, set the cookie so you authenticate the request. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: thanks for your reply..my question is, while i giving Company_Type.objects.create(user_id =1, type='customer') command in shell, objects are created.. But the same command is not working while posting the data from angular js..print c_type displays the posted value.. Then why objects are not created

Comment: First of all, you should see your ajax request in Chrome developer tools, like that http://blog.bcdsoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/dev-tools-lg.png  If you can see it, now you can see detail response, just click on response like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059071/django-are-there-any-tools-tricks-to-use-on-debugging-ajax-response P.S.: Sorry for my english, i'm learning it now. And stackoverflow is good practice )